# Recoger todos los datos de un registro usando DISTINCT en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo la siguiente consulta de SQL

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT marca 
FROM aplicacion as a 
     JOIN aplicacion_marca as a_mar ON a.id_marca = a_mar.id
```

Esta consulta solo me devuelve los registros del campo marca distintos entre si, y yo necesito todos los campos de ese registro no solo el de marca ¿Como hago? Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Pues agrega al `SELECT` las otras columnas que quieres.

Comment: Tal vez si editas tu pregunta para incluir datos de entrada y los datos de salida que esperas tendrías una respuesta, en lugar de gente tratando de adivinar lo que explicas

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a TODOS entiendo que de ambas tablas, por tanto:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, as.*
FROM aplicacion as a 
     JOIN aplicacion_marca as a_mar ON a.id_marca = a_mar.id
```

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que me traiga todos los campos de ese registro, no solo el de marca. Si hay alguna coincidencia quiero el campo id y el de aplicación también

Comment: si sabes como funciona un join?

Comment: No, estoy aprendiendo, pero el problema no es de join, es del distinct. Porque la consulta va bien y me trae los registros correctos, pero de esos registros que trae solo me devuelve el campo marca, y yo quiero tambien el resto de campos

Comment: pues prueba la consulta que he colocado y verás como trae todos los registros de la tabla aplicación y de aplicación_marca. Lo que hace el distinct es no traer FILAS duplicadas, hago énfasis en FILAS porque si una de ellas tiene un valor distinto en una columna (sea cual sea) entonces ya es un registro único, por tanto NO SE CONSIDERA duplicado y aparecerá en el output de la query.

Answer (score 0):

Colocando un * después del SELECT devuelves todos los campos de la tabla, o la unión en este caso. Sería de esta forma:

```
SELECT * DISTINCT marca
FROM aplicacion AS a
JOIN aplicacion_marca as a_mar ON a.id_marca = a_mar.id
```

Comment: Lo intente pero me da este error Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT marca FROM aplicacion AS a JOIN aplicacion_marca as a_mar ON a.id_mar' at line 1 in

Comment: Y eso es solo cuando agrego el *